# JQuery - Wrong image link loads correct image

Tags: jquery, image, json, load

So.. When testing this at the home Apache+Php5 server it all went (you all guessed) smooth. If it went smoother, i'd smell something fishy. I did.

I uploaded the code to a freewebhost (hey.. you do what you need to.) to test if all went with the same awesomeness.

..it .. "did". as the image shown in #mainRight_PubSpot is not the one's supposed to be (it's the one after, like.. it's supposed to show img1 shows img2).
Also, if you notice and read carefully the image it is loading ... doesnt exist. 
It's loading image/gal/N.jpg when the name of the files is fullN.jpg.

ps: i wanted to add some "$("#mainRight_PubSpot").css("background-image","url(image/loading.gif)");" but it doesn't seem to work.

this is how i get the images in folder

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
//alert(obj)
    $.each(obj,function(index, value){
        //alert(this);
        var n = index+1;
        //alert(""+n+" "+index);
        var nimg = new Image();
            $(nimg).load(function() {
                $(this).hide();
                $("#mainLeft_imgHold").append("<imgt imgn="+n+"></imgt>")
                $("#mainLeft_imgHold").find('imgt:last').append(this);
                $('imgt').css("background","");
                $(this).fadeIn();
            }).attr({
                src:""+this,
                imgn:""+n,
                id:"imgThumb"
                });
```

Images name/src (aka this) = image/gal/fullN.jpg (n = 1, 2, 3, N)
*note image/thumbN.jpg are exactly the same pics as /gal/fullN.jpg (even the numbers)

After doing that, i have one of those "live mouseover magic thingy" for obvious reasons

```
if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                    $("#mainRight_PubSpot").css("background-image","url(image/loading.gif)");
                     var imgN = $(this).attr("imgn");
                     var img = new Image();
                     $(img).load(function(){
                     $(this).hide();
                     $("#mainRight_PubSpot").append(this);
                     $(this).fadeIn();
                     }
                     ).attr({
                         src:"image/thumb"+imgN+".jpg",
                         width:"249",
                         height:"175",
                         id:"thumBig"
                    });
                }
```

For testing porpuses, i'm giving the link to the thing if you need any other info.
http://nfd.freehostia.com/folio/findex.html

Note: This works like it is supposed to at the home server. it even links the correct image with that non-existing link. (i know, wierd)
But it's all messy in a live webserver

ALSO: that host is slow. like.. hella slow. (that, or i have a bug in the click thing. which does not reproduce at the home server) know anyother free-fasty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your DOM in [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), in place of thumbs you have big images and in place of one big you have all thumbs, and on onlick handler you add div to the body which make no sense, and also on mouseover you add thumbs to #mainRight_PubSpot

onclick should look like this:

```
var thumb = $('#mainRight_PubSpot').append('<img class="big"/>').
  find('.big').load(function() {
   $(this).fadeIn();
});

$('imgt').live('click', function(i, item) {
   thumb.fadeOut().attr('src', 'image/thumb/img' + $(item).attr("imgn") + ".jpg");
});
```

And instead of imgt you should use div because imgt tag don't exist in HTML/XHTML.

RE ps: if you add css background now it should display loading image because big image is hidden when loading.

You don't use values from gallery.php, If you want to create a gallery from JSON you should return in gallery.php something like:

[["img/thumb01.jpg", "img/big01.jpg"] ... ]

and in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('gallery.php',
          function(data){
                 $.each($.parseJSON(data),function(index, value){
                    $('<a href="' + value[1] + '"/>').addClass('thumb').
                        append('<img src="' + value[0] + '"/>').
                        appendTo("#mainLeft_imgHold");
                    /* this could also look like this:
                    $('<a/>').attr('href', value[1]).addClass('thumb').
                        append('<img src="' + value[0] + '"/>').
                        appendTo("#mainLeft_imgHold");
                    */
                });
            });
});

$('.thumb').live('click', function() {
    thumb.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: i should have said that those divs are placed to make a overlay window. but it uses the same process as filling in the thumbs. either way, i'll re-read your code as is not making much sense to me (in particular, the on click thingy or at last that var thumb = part.)

Comment: Also, there are NO thumb images in the website (aka i've yet to make thumbs, m using a copy of the imgs in /gal/)
and could you parse <pre>$('<a href="' + value[1] + '"/>').addClass('thumb').</pre> this to engish? is it saying "add a class to the value retrieved from the json, append a img tag to it and append all of that to the holding div?"
also, the 'clicks' function you provide uses a href, won that href be 'in the way' if we click that item (as in, wont it assume it's to go to that href instead of catching tht href?).

Comment: It create jQuery object from string (link with href which is url of big image) add thumb class to that link, add image as child of that link and append this link to #mainLeft_imgHold so you have <div id="mainLeft_imgHold"><a class="thumb" href="imagebig.jpg"><img src="small.jpg"/></a>....</div>. Thumb class is for live click event.

Comment: if you put html inside jquery selector it will create DOM element and wrap it with jQuery object, so you can manipulate that object and then append it to the document.

Comment: well, this is wierd as it gets. i haven't got home yet, im at school, so i hadnt had the opp to test it out BUT.. and keep with me on this one.. if you try my home server it works 'flawlessly' (aka pics load the way it is supposed to)
http://89.154.64.207/redsmile/DonGon/findex.html

Comment: Now I know what's your code is suppose to do. The problems is that if you don't have image on server image/gal/"+n2+".jpg" then your load event on that image will not fired. But still don't remove the node just change src attribute, is faster and shorter. and load event on big image you could attached only once (when DOM node is created), it will fire if you change src attribute. And another note you should use separate live events, using "event.type == 'click'" is weird.